# Offline (visualisation) rendering in scientific computing

Tags: visualization, hpc

I have already asked this question on scientific computing and wondered if this forum could offer alternatives.

I need to simulate the movement of a large number of agents undergoing soft body deformation. The processes that govern the agents' movement are complex and so the entire process requires parallelisation.

The simulation needs to be visualised in 3D. As I will be running this simulation across many different nodes (MPI or even MPI+GPGPU) I do not want the visualisation to run in real time, rather the simulation should output a video file after it is finished.

(i'm not look for awesome AAA video game quality graphics, in addition the movement code will take up enough CPU time so I don't want to further slow the application down by adding heavy weight rendering code)

I think there are three ways of producing such a video:

- Write raw pixel information to BMPs and stitch them together - I have done this in 2D but I don't know how this would work in 3D.....
- Use an offline analogue of OpenGL/Direct3D, rendering to a buffer instead of the screen.
- Write some sort of telemetry data to a file, indicating each agents' position, deformation etc for each time interval and then after the simulation has finished use it as input to a OpenGL/Direct3D program.

This problem MUST have been solved before - there's plenty of visualisation in HPC

**In summary: How does one easily render to a video in an offline manner (very basic graphics not toy story - I just need 3D blobs) without impacting performance in a big way?**

Comment: You could simply write binary files with raw agent data using MPI-IO and then postprocess this with another tool. Besides if you write the data in some common format, there are many generic visualisation tools like Open Data eXplorer that can be used to visualise the raw data. You could also integrate the VTK framework with your code and directly output nice images/videos.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to **store the different states/positions of the vertices as single frames of a vertex animation in a suitable file format**. A suitable format would be [COLLADA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA), which is a intermediate format for 3D scenes based on XML, thus it can be easily parsed and written with general purpose XML libraries. There are also special purpose libraries for COLLADA like **COLLADA DOM** and **pycollada**. The COLLADA file containing the vertex animation could then be **rendered directly to a video file**, with the rendering software of your choice (3D Studio Max, Blender, Maya ...)